# depth first search python

Tags: python, function

checking for an element in a graph with using with using depth first search. Why always return "True"?

```
graph1 = {1: [2, 7, 8],
          2: [3, 6],
          3: [4, 5],
          4: [],
          5: [],
          6: [],
          7: [],
          8: [9, 12],
          9: [10],
         10: [],
         11: [],
         12: []}
element = int(input("Введите значение "))


def search(graph, node):
    if node == element:
        return True
    else:
        for n in graph[node]:
            search(graph, n)
    return False


print(search(graph1, element))
```

Comment: It's because you pass `ǹode` as an element in the  `print(search(graph1, element))`, so basically the first line of the `search` evaluates to `if element == element` which will always return `True`.

Comment: This is one reason why global variables are bad...

Answer (score 1):

Thats because as soon at is entering the function, it is checking the value of `node` and `element` and since you have called the function using `element` as parameter value for `node`, this condition will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

```
element = int(input("Введите значение "))
```

Here you assign to element the value you wish to find using depth-first.

You call the search function like this:

```
print(search(graph1, element))
```

And in the function, you start with:

```
def search(graph, node):
    if node == **element**:
    ...
```

`element` and `node` are the same values therefore always returning true when compared.